# Different results with df.dropna(axis='rows') and df.drop(index=np.where(df.isnull().sum()!=0)[0], axis='index')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove all rows that contain NaN values from a dataframe. However, I have realized that using `df.dropna(axis='rows')`, but using `df.drop(index=np.where(df.isnull().sum()!=0)[0], axis='index')` gives different result. The former removes fewer rows than the later.

For example, my initial dataframe has 80 cols and 91713 rows.

- If I use `dropna()` the resulting dataframe has 80 cols and 91639 rows (e.g. 74 rows were dropped).
- If I instead use `drop()` the new shape is 80 cols and 56935 rows (e.g. 34778 were dropped).

Is there something wrong with how I am getting the indices to input to `df.drop()`? I do get 74 columns if I just look at the number of indices I am dropping with that method. E.g with `df_nulls = df.iloc[np.where(df.isnull().sum()!=0)[0]]`, `df_nulls.shape[0]` is 74.

Update:
I know there is definitely something wrong with the `df.drop()` method because when I try to run further processing on the data I get errors related to the there still being NaNs. But why would `np.where(df.isnull().sum()!=0)` not find all the NaN values?

**Update 2:
it is certainly just something wrong with my indexing (see below), but shouldn't iloc give the rows?**

```
indices_rows_with_nulls = np.where(df.isnull().sum()!=0)[0] 
df_nulls = df.iloc[indices_rows_with_nulls] 
print('df.shape: '+ str(df.shape)+'   df_nulls.shape: '+ str(df_nulls.shape))
indices_rows_without_nulls = np.where(df.isnull().sum()==0)[0] 
df_no_nulls = df.iloc[indices_rows_without_nulls]
print('df.shape: '+ str(df.shape)+'   df_no_nulls.shape: '+ str(df_no_nulls.shape))
```

gives

```
df.shape: (91713, 80)   df_nulls.shape: (74, 80)
df.shape: (91713, 80)   df_no_nulls.shape: (6, 80)
```

Comment: have you tried do the opposite and see what you are left with?
`new_df = df.drop(index=np.where(df.isnull().sum() = 0)[0]`

Comment: As an initial debugging step, have you tried looking at one or more rows that aren't dropped by either method to see the commonalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum on columns

```py
df.isnull().sum(axis=1)!=0

# or

df.isnull().sum(axis='columns')!=0
```